# Диагональные элементы двухмерного массива

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Дано задание создать квадратный двумерный массив и заполнить его диагональные элементы единицами при помощи цикла. Я выполнила задание следующим образом:

```
public class lesson2dz4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0, x = arr[i].length; j < arr[i].length; j++, x--) {
                if (i == j || i == x - 1) arr[i][j] = 1;
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Но до - 1 в условии дошла методом проб и ошибок, так что логически не понимаю, откуда он берется. Если рассуждать человеческим, а не программерским языком переменная i отвечает за строки массива, переменная j - за столбцы, но если ограничиться ими двумя, то единицы вводятся только по диагонали слева направо. Чтобы получить и справа налево, введена переменная x, которая идет по столбцам в обратную сторону. Почему из нее нужно вычитать единицу?
Объясните, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в начальном значении. Массив из 3 элементов индексируется 0,1,2 но размер у него 3. У Вас `x` изначально:

```
x = arr[i].length; //здесь 3
```

Поэтому Вам на каждом повторе цикла приходится вычитать единицу. Все, что нужно - вычесть единицу при изначальной инициализации:

```
x = arr[i].length - 1;
```

Заметьте, что у Вас для `i`, `j` стоит знак строго меньше `<`.

Итого наиболее правильный вариант:

```
public class lesson2dz4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0, x = arr[i].length - 1; j < arr[i].length; j++, x--) {
                if (i == j || i == x) arr[i][j] = 1;
                else arr[i][j] = 0;
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Если задача только заполнить (без вывода):

```
public class lesson2dz4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i][i] = 1;
            arr[arr.length - 1 - i][i] = 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Но так тоже получается только одна диагональ, но ведь по факту в квадратном массиве их две.

Comment: @КаМарк как раз закончил редактировать ответ)) Не сразу вчитался в вопрос

Comment: @КаМарк если ответ Вам помог - отметьте его принятым, пожалуйста!

Comment: Если отойти от задачи "заполнить и сразу вывести", то наиболее правильный вариант для квадратной матрицы: заполнять за один проход цикла (без вложенного): `for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {arr[i][i] = 1; arr[arr.length - 1 - i][i] = 1;}`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло)

Answer (score 1):

`arr.length` - возвращает количество элементов в массиве, т. е. в моем случае `5`, но нумерация элементов начинается с `0`, т. е. `[0,1,2,3,4]` - последний элемент - `4`. Если попытаться получить элемент `arr[5]`, то получим ошибку `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` - индекс за пределами массива. Код я бы на стримах переписал:

```java
int dimension = 5;
int[][] arr = new int[dimension][dimension];

IntStream.range(0, dimension).forEach(i -> {
    arr[i][i] = 1;
    arr[i][arr.length - 1 - i] = 1;
});

Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
// [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
// [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
// [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
// [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

---

См. [Вывести крест из Х](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216573/420361)

Answer (score 0):

Правильный алгоритм с учетом вышеизложенного. Все алгоритмы, что сверху, кроме кода на стриме, выводят неверно/некорректно. Путем проб и ошибок единственно верный на Foreach.

```java
package clearsky;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class homework2n4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        int [][] arr= new int [n][n];
        for (int i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<arr.length; n= arr[i].length, j++, n--){
                if (i==j|| i==n-j ){
                    arr[i][j]=1;
                    System.out.println("на позиции  i номер " + i + " и на позиции j номер " + j + " число" + arr[i][j]);}

                else {
                    arr[i][j]=0;
                }
        }}}}
```