# Вывести крест из Х

Tags: java, массивы

Нужна помощь.
Есть задачка:

Создать двумерный массив строк. При его распечатке в консоли должен выводиться крестик из X:

```
x     x
 x   x
  x x
   x
  x x
 x   x
x     x
```

Вот мое решение:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] cross = new String[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                if (i == cross.length - 1 || i == j + 1)
                    cross[i][j] = "x";

                if (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) {
                    cross[i][j] = "x";
                }
                System.out.println(cross[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу разобраться со свойством диагоналей, которое будет задавать крест.

Answer (score 3):

Второй иф же правильный

```
if (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) {
                    cross[i][j] = "x";
```

Только, вероятно, в случае невыполнения условия нужно назначить пробел

```
}
else {
  cross[i][j] = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для определения креста будет достаточно второго условия, которое есть в вашем примере. И, конечно, стоит не забывать выводить новую строку после каждой вложенной итерации. :)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] cross = new String[5][5];
        for(int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                cross[i][j] = (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) ? "x" : " ";
                System.out.print(cross[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно одним циклом массив заполнить, или одним `Stream`:

```java
int d = 5;

String[][] arr = new String[d][d];

IntStream.range(0, d * 10 + d - 10)
        .filter(i -> i % 10 < d)
        .forEach(i -> {
            if (i / 10 == i % 10 || i / 10 + i % 10 == d - 1)
                arr[i / 10][i % 10] = "X";
            else
                arr[i / 10][i % 10] = " ";
        });

Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [X,  ,  ,  , X]
// [ , X,  , X,  ]
// [ ,  , X,  ,  ]
// [ , X,  , X,  ]
// [X,  ,  ,  , X]
```

---

См. [Диагональные элементы двухмерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216504/420361)